# Adding a GIF image to a TclTk window

Tags: r, tcl, tk-toolkit

I wish to insert a 'loading' GIF image to my tcltk window but just can't get my head around it. Following is a reproducible example:-

```
backg <- 'white'
pdlg <- tktoplevel(background=backg)
tcl('wm', 'geometry', pdlg, '500x100+450+350')
tilg <- 'Package installation in progress'
tkwm.title(pdlg, tilg)
fn <- tkfont.create(family = 'helvetica', size = 12)

nwlabel <- "    The requisite packages are being installed. This may take several    \nminutes... \n"
tllab <- tklabel(pdlg, text = nwlabel, font = fn, pady = 0, background=backg)

clickEv <- tclVar(0)

OK.but <- tkbutton(pdlg, text=' Stop ', command=function() tclvalue(clickEv) <- 1, font=fn, background='grey', pady=0)

tkgrid(tllab, columnspan=1) 
tkgrid(OK.but, row=3)

tkbind(pdlg, "<Destroy>", function() tclvalue(done) <- 2)
tkfocus(pdlg)

#This allows me to insert a GIF image but the animation is lost. Also it would be convenient if the output can be obtained using 'tkgrid' instead of 'tkpack'
pdlg2 <- tktoplevel(background='white')
loading <- tclVar()
tcl('image', 'create', 'photo', loading,
file='file path to GIF file')
trial <- tklabel(pdlg2, image=loading)
tkpack(trial)
```

An example GIF file can be downloaded from here -http://www.dlfpramericalife.com/library/images/final_loading_big.gif

Ideally, the GIF image should be placed above the 'Stop' button but below the text. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

In Tcl/Tk, it's quite easy.

```
set img [image create photo -file nameofthefile.gif]
label .l -image $img
```

I don't know R, but taking your code as a guide, I imagine something like this, but please check it!

```
img <- tkimage.create('photo', file='nameofthefile.gif')
imglab <- tklabel(pdlg, image = img)
```

... then you grid/pack/place it wherever you want. Please note that this don't work with animated gifs and I think animation must be hand-handler, using a timer which updates periodically the image content, but I never did it, nor I know how to do. You may check the [Tcl/Tk wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk) for more help.

Comment: We never did the actual animation part of animated GIFs (though you can still select which frame of the animation to show). Some people might consider that to be a feature!